# Microsoft Windows Licensing, transferring from old to "complete" new PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, license-key, licensing

In an question i asked, it seems that one phone call will help to transfer the licensed copy of windows to the replaced hardware

[Windows Licensing: Validity of transferring between burnt/working motherboards](https://superuser.com/questions/385626/microsoft-windows-licensing-validity-transferring-between-burnt-working-mother)

But,

***What if i want to buy a new PC (without a operating system installed) and discard the old PC, will i be able to use the licensed copy of winXP on my new PC without paying anything extra?***

Means, **transfer licensed copy of Winxp or Win7 to New Computer**?

Note: read a few answers but they all assume that the other computer will already have a licensed copy of Windows which needs upgrade, ***but here i am asking about transferring valid copy of RUNNING WINDOWS to my NEW BLANK COMPUTER***.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and DO NOT use Windows XP.  In a very short period of time it WILL NOT BE supported by pretty much anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.  If Windows was licensed as OEM software (it came preinstalled from the hardware seller), the license is bound to the original hardware.  You can't transfer the license to a new PC.

If it's a retail or other license, no problem, just install on the new PC as usual.

Comment: This is probably the simpliest answer.  If it's a volume license, you won't be asking this question. My guess is that it is an OEM license. It's become rare to run into XP retail licenses.